# Replacing a deeply rooted CORBA interface in legacy code

Tags: java, corba, idl

I have a legacy code project that uses a CORBA interface (let's call it "`CorbaIF`") that I want to convert to a regular Java interface in the source code.

How do I go about replacing all of _CorbaIFStub, CorbaIFOperations, CorbaIFPOA, CorbaIF, CorbaIFHolder, and CorbaIFHelper into just one CorbaIF.java?

Would this be an even remotely correct course of action:

1. Create a global package to contain any CORBA interface I want to
   convert (I might try converting others after this)
2. Create the interface CorbaIF and give it the correct method signatures
3. Refactor every import of the old interface to the new one
4. Anything else?

...And speaking of CORBA, I see a lot of methods with "holder" parameters for other CORBA interfaces.

e.g., CORBA has a "`CorbaSecondIF`" interface and a method has the parameter

```
public someMethod(CorbaSecondIFHolder varHolder){
```

Then every assignment to `varHolder` is

```
varHolder.value = someVariable;
```

What is the purpose of that? Why not just call a CorbaSecondIF parameter?

I'm relatively new to Java but astoundingly new to CORBA, so I may not be asking the right questions in the right way.

Comment: If you're new to Java and new to CORBA, don't try to refactor. You will do more harm than good. The key is small refactorings and good test suites.

Comment: I second @Kayaman, CORBA is complex even when you are not refactoring. Also, it is not clear what you are asking. Do you need to replace the CORBA based RMI with some other RMI technology? What other technology do you need to replace it with?

Comment: Or do just want to have a CORBA component with a Java interface? In that case, generate a Java CORBA component with the CORBA tool you are using. CORBA is not programming language dependent.